# Whats the quickest way to crop pics?

Tags: images, editing, photos, crop

What is the quickest tool that can let me choose a rectangle (of a predefined size) within any picture file, and it should crop it to that. Something like the tool you get when uploading a Gravatar ... remember?

Typical image editing software like Paint.NET or Photoshop is too slow, you have to open the image file, select a rectangle manually, crop, save, close ....

Comment: do you want to crop them always on the middle ?

Comment: Anywhere at all, using a movable rectangle.

Answer (score 4):

There is [JPEGCrop](http://sylvana.net/jpegcrop/), which is a Windows GUI application for most of the `jpegtran` features:

> A new -crop option has been added to jpegtran for 'lossless' cropping of JPEG images:

```
    -crop WxH+X+Y  Crop to a rectangular subarea
```

Answer (score 3):

I made a free tool to do that:

https://github.com/weclaw1/inbac

Just select the part of image you want to crop and press X to crop or Z to crop and go to the next image.

Answer (score 2):

[**ImageMagick**](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php) has [crop options](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/crop/).

Answer (score 2):

my tool of choice:

**[PhotoFiltre](http://photofiltre.free.fr/frames_en.htm)**, dead fast, free and portable.

Comment: Nice tool, though you have to keep drawing the selection box over and over again for each pic.

Comment: This sounds nice. I'll try it out too. +1

Comment: zees is a very nice tool.  Draw box, right click, crop.  And it __is__ very fast!

Comment: Consider suggesting your particular use-case to the developers of PhotoFiltre and maybe they'll add it to the next version - it sounds like a useful feature to have.

Answer (score 1):

I use MSPaint for this, and it's pretty quick. It's almost a reflex.

The fact that it loads quickly and is available on any (windows) machine you use makes it particularly appropriate.

Comment: I'm glad I'm not the only one who opens Paint on a quasi-regular basis.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't get any simpler than in Google's Picasa.

Draw the box, hit the button and you are done.

Be aware that Picasa does not make permanent changes to the image - it stores the edits and re-applies them when you view the image.

If you want to send the cropped image, or view it in another app, you would export a copy of the image.

http://picasa.google.com/#utm_campaign=en&utm_source=en-ha-na-us-bk&utm_medium=ha&utm_term=picasa

Comment: I don't want to keep "drawing the box" .. I want to define my height, width once and have the program show me a fixed size draggable box.

Comment: Apologies - I misunderstood your requirement

Answer (score 0):

If you have microsoft office it's quick and easy: 'Open with' Microsoft Office Picture Manager, Click 'edit pictures' at the top, A window will open to the right with 'crop'

Answer (score 0):

There are lot of online tools to do that quickly:
http://www.cutmypic.com
http://www.cropmyimage.net

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of searching and evaluating, i eventually found a tool called "[Click 2 crop](http://www.click2crop.com/)".
Its simple and dead fast for manual cropping. It have the options you are asking for. 
Its not free but offers a 15 day evaulation.