# Lossless rotation of photos using Windows Photo Viewer? (XP vs Win7)

Tags: windows-photo-viewer, lossless

If I wanted to rotate photos in XP using Windows Photo Viewer I was told, that it wasn't lossless rotation (so, worse quality in the rotated photo).

What about Win7 and Windows Photo Viewer? Is it lossless rotation of jpegs in Win7?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a brief experiment here with Windows 7 Pro 32bit - No it isn't lossless.

Use a dedicated image editing program (like [GIMP](http://www.gimp.org)) for *almost* (see comments below) lossless rotation/editing etc.

Comment: Thanks for performing an experiment! :-) Good to know that it's lossy rotations. Where you warned, when rotating the photo?I personnaly use GIMP for photo-editing and IrfanView to view and rotate photos (lossless). I asked the question, because some family-members like to rotate photos using Windows Photo Viewer (which I from now on will recommend them NOT to do!) ;-)

Comment: I use [FastStone Image Viewer](http://www.faststone.org/FSViewerDetail.htm) at home and it supports a lossless JPG rotate feature. I saw the comment saying you use IrfanView, it probably has the capability to do that as well.

Comment: Nope no warnings, not even an option of leaving the original alone and creating a new, rotated, updated file!

Comment: Could be funny to rotate a nice jpeg photo let say 1000 times using Windows Photo Viewer and then see the result! :-) Will it get worse for each rotation?

Comment: Lol i'll let you do that and report back... Dread to think of the amount of temporary files created doing it! ;)

Comment: AFAIK, Gimp does not support lossless rotation (for JPEG files).

Comment: There's a 'Quality' slider when saving JPG's which allows you to change the default of 85 (i assume it's %) to 100 - which is close enough to being lossless in my experience.

Comment: -1 for gimp is not lossless rotation of jpegs. Even if you open and export without modification, you are lossy already.

Comment: I have amended my answer to explain, in my experience it's 'close enough' but all depending on your application and what you are using the images for will depend on how close this is.

Comment: Thanks for the downvotes **without offering alternatives**!

Comment: it's not true. Windows 7 photo viewer does lossless rotation [Are “Windows Photo Viewer” rotations lossless?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/12361/25588)

Answer (score 1):

**Short answer:**

> If the dimensions of the image are multiples of 8 (or 16 if chroma
>   subsampling is used) then the rotations are lossless. Otherwise it is
>   not possible to rotate the image without recomputing the blocks i.e.
>   recompressing the image, which is lossy.

**Full details:**

See [here](https://photo.stackexchange.com/a/12362) for the rest of that great explanation about lossless JPEG rotation and Photo Viewer under Win 7.

I suggest you try [Xnview](http://www.xnview.com/en/index.html) as your image viewer, it has many interesting functions that I particularly like:

- advanced options for slideshows
- contact sheets creation from pictures folders
- supports [many more file types](http://www.xnview.com/en/formats.html) than the windows default one
- quick edit pics by adjusting brightness/contrast/exposure/color
- multiplatform

Make sure you comply with the licence because Xnview is [not free](http://www.xnview.com/en/register.html) for commercial use.

Comment: Thanks! Good explanation in the link you posted. And thank you for recommending Xnview. I use IrfanView to view and do basic manipulation on photos. Is Xnview open source?

Comment: Sure, I highlighted that point in my answer above: "and is opensource," :)

Comment: Heh, my question was related to your last bullet. On the website it says "freeware", but I don't think it's opensource?!

Comment: My bad, it's not opensource at all. I just found out after many years using it :/ The licence is too restrictive for my tastes too, commercial use is not free.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using the GUI-based **[Jpegcrop](http://jpegclub.org/)** Windows program, or [one of the many programs based on IJG jpegtran code](http://jpegclub.org/losslessapps.html) (although not all of them support cropping).

*(This answer was based on [this other answer](https://superuser.com/a/76778/10758), and also on [my answer on a Mac OS X Question](https://superuser.com/a/399998/10758).)*